# bubble/circle getting escaped in xaxis in Highchart Bubble graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am getting wired issue with highchart log bubble chart.In this chart, I have set dynamically min value on xaxis but when rendered graph,it escape some bubble on x-axis.Please look into [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/42yvnrf9/8/).

```
$(function() {

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bubble',
            plotBorderWidth: 1
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Highcharts Bubbles'
        },

        subtitle: {
            text: 'The <em>zMin</em> and <em>zMax</em> options are set to 0 and 100, bubbles should not become near the <em>maxSize</em>'
        },

        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1,
            min: -50,
            max: 150
        },

        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 18000
        },

        series: [{
            data: [
                [8, 6, 6],
                [10, 6, 6],
                [20, 10, 10],
                [30, 20, 20],
                [137, 17277, 17277]
            ]
        }]

    });
});
```

The first four bubble shows semicircle instead of full circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bubbles are printed in around center point, based on your data values. In this case you need to adapt scale on yAxis by tickPositioner / tickPositions  or min/max.